# How to Know Which component is loaded in router-outlet in Angular 5 and above

Tags: angular, routes, angular5

This my ap.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

How to know which component is loaded in Router outlet and then add a class on header or body depending on the component.

Just Like if Home is loaded then add a home class on the body. or if 404 page then notfound class on body

My Routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '' , component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'directory' , component: DirectoryComponent },
  { path: 'directory/:slug' , component: DirectorySingleComponent },
  { path: 'pricing' ,component: PricingComponent },
  { path: 'services' , component: ServicesComponent },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/' },
  { path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent}
];
```

Comment: Use a Service to which all Components subscribe. Then the currently loaded component sets a flag and header and footer react on it.

Comment: The `Router` service has a `url` property you can use to get the current route.

Comment: @DiabolicWords will try your method, can you provide a code example

Comment: @user184994 thanks for the idea used it for home but for 404 there is no exact url to check

Comment: @RakeshRoy You could use a `redirectTo` on that route so that it uses a specific URL `{path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent}, {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}`

Comment: @user184994 nice idea, but that's my last hope. if I do this then nothing on my site ever returned 404 . what you say ?

Comment: @RakeshRoy What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

header.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary py-3" [ngClass]="{'isNotFound': isNotFound, 'isHome': isHome}" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
```

routing

```
...
  { path: 'services' , component: ServicesComponent },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/' },
  { path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent , data: { status : 'notfound'}}
];
```

header.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.isNotFound = false;
    this.router.events
        .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .subscribe(event => {
          this.isNotFound = this.route.firstChild.data._value.status;
          if (this.isNotFound) {
            this.isNotFound = true;
          }
        });
  }
```

First, I sent data only to the notfound component then received it on header component then using `ngClass` add a class on the navbar which is outside router outlet.

This is how i solved it, Though thanks for all the advice. :)

Comment: What is this line `this.route.firstChild.data._value.status` can you explain this ?

Comment: if you console.log(this.route.firstChild) you will see the value. but i don't know why it is there. sorry

Comment: I think the code here is wrong. 
How is filter method available on  Observable<Event> without pipe here?

Comment: I think you need to `map` before you `filter`

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle this inside the component or based on a variable, you can use url property of the router to get the current component url

```
constructor(router: Router) {
this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
            console.log(event.url); //based on this change class
    });
}
```

Comment: Cant use if it's not found component in my case if you have any idea, please provide

Comment: what do you mean by not found?

Comment: like if any route not matched then i  redirect to notfound component http://prntscr.com/j2jfwf

Comment: redirectTo is the url fragment which will replace the current matched segment. https://angular.io/api/router/Routes