# How to know if a component is embedded or called from router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Hi I got a login component, so inside my login component.ts file how do I know when:

1. this component is called from router like https://my-domain/login
2. this component is included(embedded) from a parent component

Thanks all

Comment: please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720164/how-to-know-which-component-is-loaded-in-router-outlet-in-angular-5-and-above

Comment: [lifecycle-hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for your question is definitely using the `Component Lifecycle Hook`.

For instance, inside your `Login Component`, you can use the ngOnInit(){} to track if it is instantiated. Whenever the Login Component is called, the function will be called as well.

```
  constructor(private logger: LoggerService) { }
  ngOnInit(){
      this.logIt(`onInit`);
  }
```

In additional, there are a lots of Lifecycle Hooks, pick any one of those which fits your desire.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really unusual case.

One solution is to check the *route* of the application when the said login component is loaded.

[Use this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153045/angular2-get-activatedroute-url) for the different ways in which you can get the current url of the application.
Personally, I prefer this one:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
  const url = router.url;
  if(url.indexOf('login') > 0) {
    // this is component is loaded from login route
  } else {
    // this is loaded from parent component
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems much more interesting to test the class of the router component:  `this.route.snapshot.component !== this.constructor;`

example:

```
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  embedded: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.embedded = this.route.snapshot.component !== this.constructor;
  }

}
```